# ClientId can not be parsed from CF with spring-security-oauth2 and Tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, cloud-foundry

After updating from Spring boot 2.1.13 to the latest 2.2.5 Some of my Tomcat applications are failing to deploy to cloud foundry.

The error message in the logs

```
   2020-03-23T13:13:34.84-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2020-03-23 17:13:34.848  WARN 28 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.OAuth2AutoConfiguration]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestOperationsConfiguration$RequestScopedConfiguration
   2020-03-23T13:13:34.85-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2020-03-23 17:13:34.859  INFO 28 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :
   2020-03-23T13:13:34.85-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
   2020-03-23T13:13:34.86-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2020-03-23 17:13:34.865 ERROR 28 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
   2020-03-23T13:13:34.86-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.OAuth2AutoConfiguration]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestOperationsConfiguration$RequestScopedConfiguration
   2020-03-23T13:13:34.86-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:609)
   2020-03-23T13:13:34.86-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:310)
   2020-03-23T13:13:34.86-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:249)
   2020-03-23T13:13:34.86-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:599)
   2020-03-23T13:13:34.86-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.access$800(ConfigurationClassParser.java:110)
   2020-03-23T13:13:34.86-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.lambda$processGroupImports$1(ConfigurationClassParser.java:811)
   2020-03-23T13:13:34.86-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
   2020-03-23T13:13:34.86-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.processGroupImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:808)
   2020-03-23T13:13:34.86-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorHandler.process(ConfigurationClassParser.java:779)
   2020-03-23T13:13:34.86-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:192)
   2020-03-23T13:13:34.86-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:319)
   2020-03-23T13:13:34.86-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:236)
   2020-03-23T13:13:34.86-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275)
   2020-03-23T13:13:34.86-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95)
   2020-03-23T13:13:34.86-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:706)
   2020-03-23T13:13:34.86-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
   2020-03-23T13:13:34.86-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
   2020-03-23T13:13:34.86-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
   2020-03-23T13:13:34.86-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
   2020-03-23T13:13:34.86-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
   2020-03-23T13:13:34.86-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
   2020-03-23T13:13:34.86-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
   2020-03-23T13:13:34.86-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at com.kroger.cxp.app.PythonApplication.main(PythonApplication.java:11)
   2020-03-23T13:13:34.86-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   2020-03-23T13:13:34.86-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
   2020-03-23T13:13:34.86-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   2020-03-23T13:13:34.86-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
   2020-03-23T13:13:34.86-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
   2020-03-23T13:13:34.86-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
   2020-03-23T13:13:34.86-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)
   2020-03-23T13:13:34.86-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52)
   2020-03-23T13:13:34.86-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestOperationsConfiguration$RequestScopedConfiguration
   2020-03-23T13:13:34.86-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60)
   2020-03-23T13:13:34.86-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108)
   2020-03-23T13:13:34.86-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:225)
   2020-03-23T13:13:34.86-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processMemberClasses(ConfigurationClassParser.java:371)
   2020-03-23T13:13:34.86-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:271)
   2020-03-23T13:13:34.86-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:249)
   2020-03-23T13:13:34.86-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:599)
   2020-03-23T13:13:34.86-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     ... 30 common frames omitted
   2020-03-23T13:13:34.86-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'vcap.services.oauth.credentials.clientId' in value "${vcap.services.oauth.credentials.clientId}"
```

This only happens when deploying to CF, and only after the upgrade. I verified that nothing in the properties has changed, and the user provided services do have the correct values.

Comment: How do you provide the `${vcap.services.oauth.credentials.clientId}` value? Properties-file, startup parameter, environment variable etc? If you're using `application-<profile>.yml` (or `.properties`) make sure the profile is active.

Comment: application.yml with profile. Yes the profile is active because it's pulling the correct UPS definition key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/20343) introduced in Spring Boot `2.2.5.RELEASE`. It will be fixed in `2.2.6.RELEASE`, which is currently scheduled for release on 26 March 2020. For now you can back the Spring Boot version off to `2.2.4.RELEASE`.